# D3.js: Changing the tick values on x-axis based on the screen width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a responsive D3.js Bar Chart, by setting the height to `clientWidth`. Though the chart resizes after reloading in a new size, when the size is small the x-axis values overlap. I need to avoid this, how can i do it?

Script:

```
clientw = document.body.clientWidth;    

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = clientw - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Hola:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.hola+ "&deg;C"+"</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.hermanos; }));
  y.domain([0, 45]);
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Hola");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x)
      .attr("fill","grey")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.hermanos); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.hola); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height- y(d.hola); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

});

function type(d) {
  d.hola= +d.hola;
  return d;
}
```